# SELECT a non ID column in a foreign key table (TABLE B) based on the foreign key in the primary table (TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables, a STUDENT and RULES table. The student table holds data related to students and the rules table holds rules related to a particular student. 
Now on the student table, I have 5 columns as foreign keys to the rule table e.g

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RULES
(
    ID int identity not null primary key,
    RULENAME varchar
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.STUDENT
(
    ID int identity not null primary key,
    NAME varchar(50),
    SURNAME varchar(50),
    ADRESS varchar(50),
    RULE1 int not null references dbo.RULES(ID),
    RULE2 int not null references dbo.RULES(ID),
    RULE3 int not null references dbo.RULES(ID),
    RULE4 int not null references dbo.RULES(ID),
    RULE5 int not null references dbo.RULES(ID)
)
```

What I want to achieve is selecting NAME, SURNAME, ADDRESS from student table and join it with the RULENAME for each RULE foreign key in STUDENT e.g

```
NAME SURNAME ADDRESS RULE1NAME RULE2NAME RULE3NAME RULE4NAME RULE5NAME
```

I stayed up the whole night trying to crack this but sadly I'm still at square one. I will attribute that to my lack of experience in SQL but ya, can someone pretty pretty please help me?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your answers guys, dotnetom,  Bharadwaj.

I inner joined 5 times as suggested on dotnetoms answer. The query works fine but it returns the same rule for all five rules. Here's my query

```
SELECT 
STUDENT.NAME, 
STUDENT.SURNAME, 
STUDENT.ADDRESS, 
RULES.RULENAME AS RULE1NAME, 
RULES.RULENAME AS RULE2NAME, 
RULES.RULENAME AS RULE3NAME, 
RULES.RULENAME AS RULE4NAME, 
RULES.RULENAME AS RULE5NAME
FROM STUDENT s 
INNER JOIN RULES AS r1 ON STUDENT.RULE1 = RULES.ID
INNER JOIN RULES AS r2 ON STUDENT.RULE2 = RULES.ID
INNER JOIN RULES AS r3 ON STUDENT.RULE3 = RULES.ID
INNER JOIN RULES AS r4 ON STUDENT.RULE4 = RULES.ID
INNER JOIN RULES AS r5 ON STUDENT.RULE5 = RULES.ID
```

any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: So is this MySQL or SQL Server question?

Comment: You've tagged this as [tag:mysql] *and* [tag:sql-server]. Those are two different products. Did you intend to tag with both? Also, it's generally a design smell in SQL when you have *multiple* columns only differentiated by a number - the binding of students to rules probably ought to be a *separate* many-to-many table with as many *rows* as you need.

Comment: An SQL Server question. My apologies, was I suppose to specify that somehow?

Comment: Re-tagged........noob mistake

Comment: You can `left join` 5 times with the rules table.

Comment: Compare your new query with dotnetom's answer. Instead of using the table aliases r1, r2, etc, you just say RULES.ID and RULES.RULENAME. So which of the five different rules records for a student are you talking about? In my opinion this is even a flaw in SQL Server not to throw an error, because there is no RULES record any longer, but an r1 records, an r2 record etc. instead. There is no RULES record without an alias, so the query is invalid and should be considered such by SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this query:

```
SELECT 
    s.NAME, 
    s.SURNAME, 
    s.ADDRESS, 
    r1.RULENAME AS RULE1NAME, 
    r2.RULENAME AS RULE2NAME, 
    r3.RULENAME AS RULE3NAME, 
    r4.RULENAME AS RULE4NAME, 
    r5.RULENAME AS RULE5NAME
FROM STUDENT s 
    INNER JOIN RULES r1 ON s.RULE1 = r1.ID
    INNER JOIN RULES r2 ON s.RULE2 = r2.ID
    INNER JOIN RULES r3 ON s.RULE3 = r3.ID
    INNER JOIN RULES r4 ON s.RULE4 = r4.ID
    INNER JOIN RULES r5 ON s.RULE5 = r5.ID
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` will requires that all 5 `rules` must exists for a `student`. Otherwise no records will display.

Comment: All reference fields are defined as RULEX int not null, which means they will exist

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The query works. The problem now is that it returns the same rule name across all rule name aliases

Comment: RULES.RULENAME AS RULE1NAME, 
    RULES.RULENAME AS RULE2NAME, 
    RULES.RULENAME AS RULE3NAME, 
    RULES.RULENAME AS RULE4NAME, 
    RULES.RULENAME AS RULE5NAME              returns the same rule name across all 5 rule name aliases

Comment: You should not be using RULES, you need a specific alias for each one. Copy paste the query from the answer and you will get different names

Comment: Thanks! it works. Just made a nood mistake again. Thank you Dotnetom! It feels like I've just unloaded a massive 'number 2', euphoria I'm feeling. Was wrestling with this the entire day yesterday. Just goes to show how far experience goes............i'll get there as well. Thanks again